Tried to write a code to print all perfect numbers from 1 to 1000. Program doesn't give an output
Got into learning c++ few days ago and today I learnt about loops. I tried to write a program to give me all the perfect numbers between 1 - 1000;
I think the program should give me all the perfect numbers between 1-1000 but it doesn't give any output. what have I done wrong here?
p.s. This is my first question on this website, please forgive me for any mistakes.
The Program [Edited to deal just in integers]:
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    for (int z = 1; z <= 1000; z++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < z; i++) {
            int k = 0;
            
            if ( z % i == 0 ) {
                k = k + i;
            }
                                   
            if ((i == (z - 1)) && (k == z) )  {
                cout << k;
            }
        }
    }
}
   

expected outcome : 6 is a perfect number, 28 is a perfect number, 496 is a perfect number,
actual outcome : NIL

First advice : do NOT mix integer and floating point calculations. And NEVER compare floating point values for equality. So first thing to do is to modify your code to only use integers

To stress the point in the comment above: as an example (z / i) - int(z / i) is a floating point expression. Comparing it to zero might not give you what you expect. See e.g. : Is floating point math broken?.

A more "fun" way to learn about floating point numbers and their limitations is to watch this (lighthearted) video Floating Point Numbers - Computerphile

@PepijnKramer  Edited the code to deal just with integers. The problem still persists.
You are right, I didn't pay much head to that. I skipped the modulo operator while learning about types of operators and hence had to write <(z / i) - int(z / i) == 0> for checking whether z is divisible by i.

Think about the effect of starting each inner iteration with int k = 0; (Print k before and after k = k + i;, and start with a smaller upper bound than 1000.)

@molbdnilo Holy shit, it worked! Just had to declare (int k = 0) in beginning of the first for-loop, instead of the second one. Thanks man!

@Derek I imroved the format of your code but your last edit reverted it. Please remove unneeded spaces and use proper indentation (e.g. 4 spaces)  - it makes reading the code a lot easier.

Oh, sorry about that! I didn't knew others could edit my code so I didn't pay attention! My question is now solved, Thank you so much for giving your time, help and advice!

I didn't knew others could edit my code StackOverflow is not a user forum. Instead its a Q&A repository. The #1 purpose of a question is not to help the person asking. Instead it's actually to help future readers solve the same focused problem in the future. We (people with sufficient reputation) can edit a question in an attempt to make it a better suited question to help future readers.

For posterity, a guide to determine perfect numbers from the sequence of numbers between 1 - n.
First determine the aliquot sum of the number i from the sequence of numbers between 1 - n.
int aliquot_sum(unsigned int i)
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
        if (i % j == 0) 
            sum += j;
    return sum; 
};
Next check if i is equal to its aliquot sum. If it is, add it to the sequence of perfect numbers and return the end result.
#include <vector>

std::vector<unsigned int> get_perfect_numbers(unsigned int n)
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> perfectNumbers;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if(i == aliquot_sum(i))
            perfectNumbers.push_back(i);
    return perfectNumbers;
};

A bonus for extra performance. The for loop run by aliquot_sum doesn’t need to run until j < i but can run until j < (i/2 + 1). I’ll leave this as an exercise for the reader to implement.

Trying to find your bug, I refactored your main() code to this:
int main()
{
    for (int z = 1; z <= 1000; z++)
    {
        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < z; i++)
        {
            if (z % i == 0)
                k += i;
        }

        if (k == z)
            std::cout << k << std::endl;
    }
}

And this works perfectly!
So now, it's a matter of figuring out what my main() code does differently from your main() code.  Do you see it?
Try figuring it out before continuing.
Do you see it yet?  In your code, k gets initialized to 0 every time through the inner loop.  You don't want that.  You want k to be initialized once per iteration of the outer loop.
In my opinion, in your code you're putting too much in your inner loop.  For example, why check to see if you're at the inner loop's last iteration to run some code, when you could just as easily put that code after the inner loop?  It's easier to read that way, as it's less cluttered (and less indented).
And of course, in your effort to fill up your inner loop, you accidentally initialized k in there, when the initialization of k should be in the outer loop, before the inner loop occurs.
